# Absolute measure of activity

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, gamma-rays

I am generally quite stuck and not sure what the absolute measure of activity is, and relating to my data is more confusing.

So I am trying to calculate the absolute measure of activity of a caesium 137 source from my graph

[image: C137]

From my lab script

> Determine the absolute measure of the activity of both sources. In order to do this, you’ll need to consider both the area of the detector and its distance from the source. Remember that the sources emit γ-rays over a solid angle of 4π steradians.

So I calculate the solid angle of the detector like so:

$$\Omega=\int \frac{\cos\alpha}{r^2}$$

Using a bit of geometry I got to the integral

$$\Omega=2\pi d \int \frac{a}{(a^2+d^2)^{3/2}}da=2\pi \left(1-\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+d^2}}\right)$$

where $a=$radius and $d=$distance from source to detector

so measure in the lab,the radius is $22.4\:\rm mm$ and the distance is $2.5\:\rm mm$ plunging this I make $\Omega=5.6$.

So now from what I have glimmed for google searches etc that the absolute efficacy of a detector is given by 
$$E_\mathrm{abs}=\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}.$$

So this is where I am stuck, because I cant seem to find how to go from here to the Absolute measure of activity, my thoughts are that I am suppose to find the area under the Photopeak and dived the total number of observed counts by the time, which 
$$\frac{\text{observed count}}{\text{time}}=\frac{304569}{240\:\rm s}=1269.15/\rm s$$ 
and then take this value and multiply it by the my value for $\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}$ which I understand is the probability of it hitting the detector which worries me as my number for $\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}>1$.

Addtional information

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close.  The only thing left is to recognize that you're only going to detect about half of the actual decay events because the rest will produce gamma rays which are shooting away from your detector.  The exact fraction depends on the solid angle covered by your detector, of course, but since your sample is pretty much right up against the detector face, it'll be about half (which is reflected in your calculation $\frac{\Omega}{4\pi} \approx 0.44 \sim \frac{1}{2}$).

So, if your detector measures 1270 decays per second, and you know that that's only half of the total activity $A$ of the source, what is $A$?

---

> [...] and then take this value and muliply it by the my value for $\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}$ which I understand is the probability of it hitting the detector which worries me as my number for $\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}>1$

$\frac{\Omega}{4\pi}$ is the probability that a gamma ray hits the detector.  $\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}$ is the number of actual decays you have for every one which gets counted.

In other words,
$$\text{counts} = \frac{\Omega}{4\pi} \times \text{decays} \implies \text{decays} = \frac{4\pi}{\Omega} \times \text{counts}$$

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing from your lab manual doesn't make much sense. Is it online at a URL you could point us to? Either you're missing part of the relevant material from the lab manual or the person who wrote it isn't very competent.

The efficiency of a gamma-ray detector depends in a simple way on the geometry and in an extremely complicated way on the energy. If you graph the efficiency as a function of energy, for a fixed geometry, it will look like some kind of bell-shaped curve. It will never equal 100% of the geometrical efficiency (solid angle over four pi), as this lab manual seems to imply. At the ~700 keV energies you're dealing with, there is a significant probability that the gamma ray will either pass through the detector entirely or compton scatter inside the active volume of the detector, leaving only part of its energy and not contributing to the photopeak.

In order to find the absolute intensity of a source, the standard technique (and also the only technique I know of that gives better than order-of-magnitude precision) is to calibrate over a range of energies using sources of known intensity, then interpolate to find the efficiency at the energy of the unknown source.

> So now from what I have glimmed for google searches etc that the absolute efficacy of a detector is given by 
>   $$E_\mathrm{abs}=\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}.$$
>   [...] which I understand is the probability of it hitting the detector which worries me as my number for $\frac{4\pi}{\Omega}>1$.

You have this factor upside down. If the solid angle of the detector approaches zero, the geometrical efficiency approaches zero, not infinity.

Comment: I can actually but on url, but what I can do is print screen the lab in but I directly copied and pasted that in from the lab script. But what you described is what I read in Knoll but out lab demonstrator told us to image the surface are of two sphere and compare, which is what lead me to my orgniall and in my post except i used the solid angle.

Comment: They do tell you to measure the probability of Compton scattering, which could be used to improve on the purely geometric estimate of the efficiency. However, it still won't give you an absolute calibration, because you don't have any way of knowing how many gammas simply pass through the detector without interacting.